# Ever since changing to Windows 11 we have some workstations that now and then try to connect via smart card, but we don't use smart cards

Tags: windows, windows-11, certificate, authentication

Ever since changing to Windows 11 we have some workstations that now and then try to connect via smart card, but we don't use smart cards.

The event occurs with the computer's account, not a user's account, which is also interesting.

> Event ID: AUDIT_FAILURE(4771)
> Domain:  [Domain/Server]
> SID:  [sid]
> Account Name: [computer account (not user account)]
> Service Name: krbtgt/[domain]
> Client Address: [ip]
> Port: [port]
> Ticket Options: 0x40810010
> Failure Code: 0x10
> Pre Auth Type: 16
>
> Ticket Options:
> 0x40810010 - Forwardable, Renewable, Canonicalize,
> Renewable-ok
>
> 1
> Forwardable
> (TGT only). Tells the ticket-granting service that it
> can issue a new TGT—based on the presented TGT—with a different
> network  address based on the presented TGT.
>
> 8
> Renewable
> Used in combination with the End Time and Renew Till
> fields to cause tickets with long life spans to be renewed at the KDC
> periodically.
>
> 15
> Name-canonicalize
> To request referrals, the Kerberos client MUST
> explicitly request the "canonicalize" KDC option for the AS-REQ or
> TGS-REQ.
>
> 27
> Renewable-ok
> The RENEWABLE-OK option indicates that a renewable
> ticket will be acceptable if a ticket with the requested life cannot
> otherwise be provided, in which case a renewable ticket may be issued
> with a renew-till equal to the requested end time. The value of the
> renew-till  field may still be limited by local limits, or limits
> selected by the individual principal or server.
>
> Failure Code:
> 0x10
> KDC_ERR_PADATA_TYPE_NOSUPP
> KDC has no support for PADATA type (pre-authentication data)
> Smart card logon is being
> attempted and the proper certificate cannot be located. This problem
> can happen because the wrong certification authority (CA)  is being
> queried or the proper CA cannot be contacted in order to get Domain
> Controller or Domain Controller Authentication certificates for the
> domain controller. It can also happen when a domain controller doesn't
> have a certificate installed for smart cards (Domain Controller or
> Domain Controller Authentication templates).
>
> Pre Auth Type:
> 16
> PA-PK-AS-REQ
> Request sent to KDC in Smart Card
> authentication scenarios.

I would like to get it to stop, but I have been having difficulty nailing it down.
Wanted to see if anyone else has run into something similar and found a solution.

Comment: This is not an issue here.  Were these machines with issues upgraded from Windows 10 or fresh install?   If upgraded, take one problem machine, back up, install Windows 11 fresh and see it the issue ceases.

Comment: they came factory installed with windows 11, but they were updated to windows 11 22h2

Comment: Ask the computer manufacturer for support.  I have Windows 11  22H2 production machines and 1 Windows 11 Insider and no issues here.

Comment: ok, thank you!!

Comment: Or try stopping and disabling the three the Smart Card services. If that works on a test machine, just export the Registry settings for those services, and use the .reg file to fix the others. In *HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services*: SCardSvr, ScDeviceEnum, & SCPolicySvc

Comment: Thanks for the info, will look into that